# C# Ajax - PartialView replacing whole page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, unobtrusive-validation

I have a button and a droplist, when I press the button first my partialView is normally replaced.

But when I change an element in the list first and THEN I press the button, my whole page is replaced by my partial.

I checked around and saw that the jquery.unobtrusive was solving that issue for a lot of people but it was already included on my project.

Droplist :

```
        $(document).on("change", ".RefreshList", function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("RefreshList", "Feuillet")",
                data: $("#form0").serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                $('#header').html(response);
            },
            });
        });
```

Controller :

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RefreshList(CreationModificationFeuillet model, string actionName)
        {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Feuillet/CreationModification/Partial/Generale/PartialHeaderCreation.cshtml", model);
        }
```

Button :

```
        $("button[value='ContractSearch']").click(function () {
            $("#modalMessage").modal('show');
            $("#form0").attr("action", "@Url.Action("Creation" + Model.TypeProduit, "Feuillet")").attr("data-ajax-success", "AjaxFunction").attr("data-ajax", "true").attr("data-ajax-update", "#header").attr("data-ajax-mode", "replace");
        });
```

Controller :

```
     ...
     case "ContractSearch":
                // doStuff
return PartialView("~/Views/Feuillet/CreationModification/Partial/Generale/PartialHeaderCreation.cshtml", model);
```